# Can I check if there is a boarding pass or airline ticket in my name?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, flight-status

In my company we have a Xmas trip every year. These trips are organized by the CEO. Every year is a new place and no one knows the destination. What happens is we have to pack thigns for winter session and summer session.

I'm trying discover the final destination based on the time of we leave from the airport. This doesn't work because we might change planes somewhere on the way.

I would like know if there is a place where can I check if there are an airline ticket or boarding pass in my name?

I don't think there exists a international place with this information, at least in Europe. This look likes it would be more CIA/FBI information.

Comment: Do you mean "boarding pass" or perhaps "airline ticket"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're asking so I've gone ahead and cleaned up the question. Feel free to edit again if it's not as you intended -- I think it's more likely to get an answer if it's easier to understand. Also, are you just curious or is there some reason you would need to know the destination? If you have an international workforce you'd be better off trying to work out what places they have the visas (or don't need visas) for and then trying to narrow that down with timing.

Comment: The company and the employees are Europeans. It means we can travel to Iceland like the last Xmas or to Grand Canaries was two trips ago. At the moment no one needs visa. But we need packed summer and winter wear.

Comment: With just a name and a departure date & timeslot, I don't think you'll be able to find much. If you had the booking reference it would be possible, but without (and not event he airline), it's much more difficult, especially since it's probably a group booking.

Comment: As an aside - the season in the canaries is Winter as much as it is in Iceland. They just have very different winters.

Comment: Imagine the privacy problem, if anyone could just say: "Does Gabriel Silva have a ticket?"

Comment: Your name alone is not a unique identifier, so there could be multiple tickets with your name on them. Remember the story of the [man looking for someone with the same name as his ex](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/dec/18/man-find-woman-same-name-ex-girlfriend-round-world-trip)?

Comment: Wow, I would love to work at this company :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: I would hate it. If such "secret mystery travel" was compulsory, I would stay home and let them fire me; otherwise I would stay home and start polishing off my CV so I could find someone saner to work for anyway.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - I've known of one other company that did a similar surprise trip every year, and attendance was optional -- you could always choose to stay back and work if you didn't want to participate in the "mystery trip". Some essential staff were required to stay back at the office and were rewarded with a bonus, but if you were eligible for the trip and chose not to go, you got nothing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Does Gabriel Silva have a ticket?" is a privacy problem. "I'm Gabriel Silva and I'd like to know if I have a ticket", is not. There's nothing to stop someone with sufficient time on their hands from calling every single airline and asking to "verify my ticket details", provided you can convince them that you are really that person.

Comment: Have you considered socially engineering the answer out of whoever the CEO tasked to plan this part of the trip?

Comment: Can i get your boss' number? I am going to resign now! He can even book me for Mars

Comment: @JBentley but that's just it.  How would the airline know whether any of the Gabriel Silva tickets in their system were booked on behalf of the Gabriel Silva who is asking?

Comment: @phoog Well, as I described in my answer, there is no clear cut answer to that. There is no easy way for a company to ever really *prove* that they're speaking to the real Gabriel Silva. The best they can usually do is establish that the person they're talking to knows things, or has possession of things, that Gabriel Silva might be expected to. In practice such things are very weak forms of evidence (e.g. confirming a date of birth, or a booking reference number).

Comment: @JBentley point taken, but I'm thinking not of proving that the person asking is the *real* Gabriel Silva, but rather that he is the *same* Gabriel Silva.  In other words, Gabriel Silva could show up in person with his passport and 3 other photo IDs and his fingerprints, and they might give him information about a flight booked for his fourth cousin Gabriel Silva, or indeed a completely unrelated Gabriel Silva.  Date of birth would solve virtually all instances of that problem, but I do not remember ever giving an airline my date of birth when I booked a ticket.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I really like work in this company.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it isn't compulsory. But no one miss this Xmas travel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot.

This information is not available to the public nor is it obtainable from the airline(s) without some court order.

I would imagine it is near impossible for even normal law enforcement to get it as there is no "show me anyone who has a flight booked on this date" query possible (as far as I know), since this information is distributed between the global GDS systems.

I would not put it beyond the reach of some clandestine intelligence organization though.

Even when law enforcement wants to know if someone has booked a flight, they usually have their name and another variable - such as a credit card or bank information against which to check; and then they work the way back to the airline.

However, I can imagine a scenario at a local airport where there are a handful of airlines, that law enforcement can compel them to reveal their bookings for that day - but that would have to be under court order and not without serious implications.

For the boarding pass, it gets even more difficult.

Just keep the surprise a surprise. :)

---

If you really do want to get to know this information; it is highly likely your boss used a travel agent to book these tickets (as group bookings are commonly done through agents - because online sites generally have a limit on the number of tickets; and agents usually give better discounts on such packages).

So, I would do some low-tech sleuthing and try to find out which travel agency the company uses. Chances are high it was the same one that was used last time.

Comment: It's always possible in all the movies and TV series I ever watched, few clicks and the police can find out if Mr. X has a ticket. Also a hacker could do that in movies.

Comment: We don't live in a movie @inactive :)

Comment: @JasonHeine don't be a grinch :(

Comment: Government agencies will have access to the [Passenger Name Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record).

Comment: This may not be true. Under the EU's Data Protection Directive, there is a right to find out personal information that a company or organisation holds about you. The asker can find out how to make the request under their country's legislation.

Comment: Yeah, but who is he going to ask? All the airlines flying out of an airport?

Comment: Sure, why not? But I'm simply pointing out that your sentence "This information is not available to the public nor is it obtainable from the airline(s) without some court order", is incorrect within the EU. You do not need a court order to access your own personal information.

Comment: @MJeffryes the interesting problem here is proving it's you, though. Unless, eg, passport details have been recorded, there might not be a practical way to distinguish between the John Smith wanting to know their flight details, and the "John Smith" wanting to know someone else's flight details. The privacy protections might override disclosure in this case.

Answer (score 8):

One of the provided answers is wrong, at least in the UK (and probably throughout the EU). Under the Data Protection Act you have the right to request any and all data that a company has recorded about you (with some exceptions) and even in some cases, data which is not about you but has some direct effect upon you.

Taking the legal route, you would have to put the request in writing (a "subject access request") and cover the company's admin costs (up to a statutory limit of £10). They have up to 40 days to respond, after which they are breaking the law. It is highly unusual for a company to dispute your identity for SARs, but attaching a copy of your passport should lay any such concerns to rest.

It's not necessary to take the legal route however. Virtually every company you contact by telephone in the UK will provide any information they have to hand about you, so long as you can convince them that you are that person. This will usually consist of two or three simple "data protection" questions, such as asking you to verify your address, date of birth, account number, etc. In the context of an airline they might ask you for your booking reference number or some such similar information. You probably don't have that info.

Even if you are unable to answer all of the data protection questions, that isn't the end of your options. Most companies will have a process for resolving queries where a customer forgets or cannot locate certain details. This might involve emailing a copy of your passport, for example. If it were me, I'd simply call up the airline and tell them the truth - "someone else has booked a ticket; I don't know the destination or booking reference, but it's in my name and I would like to know the details".

The fact that you do not know the airline is not an issue, because you can simply contact them all. Yes, it is time consuming, but a time constraint wasn't part of the question. A mass email to all of the might net some responses straight off the bat, reducing the number of calls you need to make.

It's worth noting as well that a lot of companies are quite lax when it comes to this stuff. I've been able to get past data protection questions with answers that anyone else purporting to be me could easily give. Just today, as part of my job, I needed to contact a utility company and I failed a data protection question. I was able to get past it by simply sending them a blank email from my work email address, and the fact that the name on the account was a partial match to the domain name of my email address, was sufficient. It is trivially easy to fake such an email.

Comment: With a lot of Airline group bookings for big groups, you don't actually need to give the names until quite close to departure. So, it could be that the OP's boss has 30 seats booked for $SOMEWHERE_FUN with $AIRLINE, but at this stage the airline has no idea who will be flying, so a Data Protection style request won't turn up anything interesting at this stage....

Answer (score 7):

Your name is not a unique identifier, and as such is insufficient to identify you.

However, it is likely that your organization has provided either your Identity Card number of Passport number when it reserved in your stead, and THIS is a unique identifier. Likewise if you have a frequent flyer number.

The next hurdle is that there is no central repository of all flights; there are some large GDS (Sabre and Amadeus), however not anybody may query their database for obvious reasons.

That being said, most companies only work with a subset of airline companies: it is likely that one of the airline used in the trip (if there are several) will be a "usual" airline for your company. Check the airlines used for business trips and the past Xmas trips.

Then, once you have the airline(s) to check, find out their reservation websites on Google and try to identify yourself with your ID card number, Passport number, Frequent Flyer number... (whichever is available). Most websites allow identification without the reservation number or e-ticket number simply because you may have lost it.

Comment: If your frequent flier number was used, you should already have a login that'll show you any upcoming flights.

Answer (score 3):

Tackling the real issue of finding out the location instead of getting the information from the airline… Have you attempted to grab the information from the intermediaries?

For instancem the company may be booking through the same intermediary every year. In that case, you may be able to know from them which weather to expect by asking the "right questions".

Answer (score 1):

In USA, if you know the departure airline, you can call them, persuade them of your identity, and find out what they have on you.

Comment: Do you have any source to support this?  What could you use as a unique identifier?

Comment: They will ask you things that which aren't really secure but which they think are.  Name, birthday, etc. Primary source: personal experience.  If you have (or register for) an account at the airline's website, you can probably even find out online (I haven't tried it though).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying discover the final destination based on the time of we leave from the airport. This doesn't work because we might change planes somewhere on the way.
>
> I would like know if there is a place where can I check if there are an airline ticket or boarding pass in my name?

If you know the exact time of your flight, you can call the airline, and they can locate your itinerary by looking for your name in the manifest for that flight.  (They will likely ask for personal information to verify your identity.)  Once they find your itinerary, then should be able to tell you the connecting flights or the locator (PNR) which you can usually use to see your itinerary on the airline's site.

However, be aware that the itinerary in the first airline's system might not be your complete itinerary: if the trip was booked by an airline or travel agency that uses a different reservation system (GDS) from that of the first airline, then there may be subsequent flights that do not appear in the itinerary as it is in the reservation system of the first airline.  For example, if the first airline is BA, but the trip was booked by a travel agency that uses Sabre, then the itinerary as seen by BA might only be, say, AAA-BBB, even if there is a connecting flight on another airline BBB-CCC.